# How can I find a string with a single '=' using find and visual studio 2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I have tried the following two expressions in order to search for an assignment within my code.  For some reason, neither works and I do not understand why.  I am using the Find and Replace dialogue within Visual Studio 2010.

```
// I thought that :b was the ms code for whitespace
m_Events.*[=][:b]


// I thought that [=][^=] will match an = followed by anything except another =.
m_Events.*[=][^=]
```

Both of the above expressions match lines with `==` but I only want to find things with a single `=` within.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have [not "="] on both sides of the "=":

```
m_Events.*[^=]=[^=]
```

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed it.  I also changed it to filter out a few other possibilities like so m_Events.+[^=!<>][=][^=]